# Spring Security this kind of http://localhost:8080/WEB/edit-employee/{ID} url not authenticating

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured one spring security context for my project by using intecept-url i am able to authenticate all URLS but when i pass some ID over URL authentication is not happening.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

Working URLS

```
http://localhost:8080/WEB/add-employee
http://localhost:8080/WEB/view-employee
```

Not working URLS

```
http://localhost:8080/WEB/edit-employee/1
http://localhost:8080/WEB/edit-employee/2
```

1 and 2 are the ID iam passing over URL the above URL patterns are not working (that means when i passing ID over URL)

And i have tried many combinations in intercept-url but i am not getting the correct result.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/> <!-- this means all URL in this app will be checked if user is authenticated -->

        <!-- We will just use the built-in form login page in Spring -->
        <form-login login-page="/" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"  default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/> <!-- the logout url we will use in JSP -->
    </http>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line `<intercept-url pattern="/edit-employee/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>` to disallow anonymous access to that URL.

Comment: I have removed that line but still the problem is existing.

Comment: @DON: Can you provide some background information? Specifically, what sort of content is mapped to the URL http://localhost:8080/WEB/edit-employee/2 ? That seems like REST URL.

Comment: I have a page called employee list in which all the registered employees where list with a view detail button for each employee. When i click on the view details button of an employee corresponding ID of that user will pass to "edit-emplyee" by using  localhost:8080/WEB/edit-employee/{ID} this. I am able to edit the employee details in that page but i am unable to get the corresponfding employee ROLE under   localhost:8080/WEB/edit-employee/{ID} this url.